# Update table using same table in where class

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Hi i am updating my table column using the same table in where class but its giving me error :

> You can't specify target table 'orderitem' for update in FROM clause

Here is my query :

```
update orderitem set status = 3 where id in 
(select oi.id from `order` o inner join orderitem oi on oi.order_id = o.id where o.time < 1514764800 and oi.status = 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `oi.status` in the subquery?  It suggests that the `order` table is not needed at all.

Comment: I need `order` table too. See my question again

Answer (score 1):

Use a `join` instead:

```
update orderitem oi join
       `order` o
       on oi.order_id = o.id 
    set oi.status = 3
    where oi.status = 1 and o.time < 1514764800;
```